# Android Send Bluetooth Message Receives Space Character

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am making communication between an 2013 Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.4 and an Arduino Mega 2560 with an HC-06 bluetooth unit. I have established a connection from the Nexus 7 to the HC-06 and have gotton data to the Nexus from the Arduino but I am unable to transfer data from the Nexus 7 to the Arduino. I get no errors when I transfer data in Android, but the Arduino receives a space instead of the character I sent.

Android write method:

```
public void write(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
        }
    }
```

Sends data:

```
public static void sendInfo(String info) {
    boolean isErr = false;
    if (MainActivity.isConnected) {
        Log.d(TAG, "In sentInfo()");
        //Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + info + "...");
        //TO(done)DO: send info to bluetooth device (Arduino)


        try {
            mConnectedThread.write(info);
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            isErr = true;
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to send message \"" + Arrays.toString(msg) + "\" with error \"" + n.getMessage() + ".\"");
        }

        if (!isErr) {
            Log.i("sentInfo", "In sentInfo(), this was sent: " + Arrays.toString(msg));
            //noinspection ALL
            isErr = false;
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mThis, "Please connect the Arduino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Arduino receive code:

```
int setMsg() {
   if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
      chars = Serial1.available();
      incomingByte = Serial1.read();
      putstring("You've Got Mail!  Characters: ");
      Serial.print(chars);
      putstring("  Message: '");
      Serial.print(incomingByte);
      putstring_nl("'.");
      if        (incomingByte == 49) {
         return 1;
         flashLED(500);
         Serial.println(msg);
      } else if (incomingByte == 50) {
         return 2;
         flashLED(500);
         Serial.println(msg);
     } else if (incomingByte == 51) {
         return 3;
         flashLED(500);
         Serial.println(msg);
      } else if (incomingByte == 52) {
         return 4;
         flashLED(500);
         Serial.println(msg);
      } else if (incomingByte == 53) {
         return 5;
         flashLED(500);
         Serial.println(msg);
      } else if (incomingByte == 100) {
         return 6;
         flashLED(500);
         Serial.println(msg);
      } else {
         Serial.println(incomingByte);
         digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
         delay(3250);
         digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
         delay(20);
         return 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Please explain why the Arduino's `Serial` always prints
`You've Got Mail!  Characters: 1  Message: ' '.` when the Nexus 7 sends any message (I only send numbers in quotes to the `sendInfo()` function) to the HC-06.

Comment: I defined `incomingByte` as a `char` at the top of my sketch.

Answer (score 0):

- What type have you made incomingByte an int?

Edit in response to your comment:

[incomingByte needs to be an int](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read).

Change your read code to:

[Arduino Mega example:](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/available)

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // read from port 0, send to port 1:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial1.print(inByte, BYTE); 

  }
  // read from port 1, send to port 0:
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(inByte, BYTE); 
  }
}
```

> (I only send numbers in quotes to the sendInfo() function) to the HC-06.

You should not be sending numbers in quotes, just a number. That could be your problem, as it is reading the quotation mark.

- also, it might be better to use a switch instead of all those ifs
- Also this `byte[] msg = info.getBytes();` in `sendInfo(String info) {`is an unnecessary line, you're not using it from what I can see, you parse the string to byte array in the `write(string) method`

Instead of `Log.i("sentInfo", "In sentInfo(), this was sent: " + Arrays.toString(msg));`
you can have `Log.i("sentInfo", "In sentInfo(), this was sent: " + info);`

and all the stuff you have after return in each if, will not be executed

```
return 1;
flashLED(500); 
Serial.println(msg);
```

Anything you want to execute within each if statement needs to be put in before the return statement, The return will cause your function to finish and return to the calling function.

Comment: I changed it accordingly, but now it always gets `You've Got Mail!  Characters: 1  Message: '0'.` no matter what the message sent!

Comment: I believe that the `mmOutputStream` is sending the digit I want sent in ASCII form, using `byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();`. I am not sending any quotes. I am getting the number from a handful of buttons a user could press, which is supposed to send the a number string, like this:`ArduinoTools.sendInfo("5");`(The `sendInfo()` function, as viewed above, is kept in another `.java` file) I have gotten this to work before, but I don't know what's wrong now or how to solve the issue.

Comment: The `BYTE` keyword is no longer supported. Pity.